# Google Wallet/PHP: Handling Postbacks with uncertain charge result

Tags: php, android-pay

In PHP, when handling the postback from Google Wallet confirming a purchase, it's possible that the server will not reply within the ten second time limit--this is sometimes completely undetectable serverside.

What should I do to prevent this? Is there a way to confirm the purchase was successful?

Comment: You are aware that Google Wallet is being end-of-lifed later this month (November 20), right? https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449

Comment: That's Google checkout...

Comment: The two services are closely related. You may want to double check that you won't be affected.

Comment: Google Wallet for digital goods is completely unchanged with the end-of-life of the Google Checkout service, and should have no effect on answers to this question.

Comment: Trust me, I know what service I'm using..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Google Wallet for Digital Goods* will fail for both you (merchant) and the user/buyer if you don't respond to the postback as required.

> Important: If you specify a postback URL, your server must respond promptly and correctly to the HTTP POST messages that Google sends for each transaction. Otherwise, the transaction will be canceled.

REF: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback

If you're saying your system may think the trnx is "good" and it just took time to respond (at which point Google already canceled) - there is a "verification step" that occurs on successful transactions - [success handler](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#successhandler). You can use that to "confirm" the order on your end. So if Google canceled the transaction, your system will not get this final (re)confirmation (because your success handler will not be called).

I guess you could also use the *failure handler* for this, though it won't have an "orderId"

Hth...

---

As a side note on the comments, Google Checkout was also renamed Wallet at some point. If memory serves, it was really more for buyers than for merchants...so yes, do check on what API you are referring to.

This answer is specific to Wallet For Digital Goods (it is completely separate from Google Checkout/Wallet, which also included some support for digital purchases).

See this [link announcement](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449?hl=en&ref_topic=3080448)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a clientside confirmation, not a serverside confirmation. While it would be useful and possible to have the client tell the server that the order was successful, it's not possible to rely on that--EG, the client's message could fail.

Comment: @JoshuaCoffey You will pass the client side info back to your server for validation.

Comment: The issue is not with making sure the payment actually went through; the issue is with the client not actually being able to send the request to the server.

Comment: Rather, the concern isn't primarily with the client forging it.

Comment: @JoshuaCoffey Hmmm I'd say you could redirect the client, but that still relies on some client side stuff...I'd think the only thing left is manual (Merchant Center).

Comment: A mix of client verification and merchant center for those rare cases that it doesn't work would probably work well. Thanks.